# Unramified Galois extension of a function field of a curve - definition

Tags: galois-theory, curves, function-fields, ramification

Reading some papers I've encountered the following: Let $X$ be a smooth curve over a field $K$ with function field $K(X)$. Consider the maximal Galois extension of $K(X)$ which is unramified over $X$.

I don't understand what it means for a Galois extension of $K(X)$ to be unramified over $X$. Can anyone give me the definition please? The only definitions of unramified extensions I've found talk about valuations etc.

Comment: It's about valuations. See any algebraic number theory book

Comment: Any particular one which will talk about being unramified over a curve? I can't find anywhere what is meant by that.

Comment: Cassels and Frolicher is the standard book for algebraic number theory.

Comment: Still can't see the definition of that in the book you recommended

Comment: Ok, I think you don't know the fact that unramified extensions corresponds to unramified (finite) coverings of $X$. So you just want the maximal unramified extension of $K(X)$ such that the corresponding curve is unramified over $X$.